# Is there a better way to convey "completely motivated and ready to work"?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a cover letter and I think that my use of *adjust myself* in this sentence sounds rather weak.

> Since I am experienced at this topic, I believe that I could (adjust myself) to the collaboration more quickly.

I doubt that "adjust oneself to" conveys the right impression here: should I use something different?

It should explain that I could get involved quickly and start to be useful and fully dedicated, since I'm experienced.

Comment: Well there're a lot of business jargon terms that could fit.

Answer (score 1):

... since I have a lot of experience in this topic, I believe that I could soon be up to speed.

> **up to speed**
>
> a. operating at an acceptable or competitive level

[[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/up-to-speed)]

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean that the person in question is likely to *get productive*, or in one word, ***contribute*** at the earliest.

> Since I am experienced at this topic, I believe that I could ***contribute*** to the collaboration more quickly.

M-W:

> **[contribute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute)**
> *Intransitive verb*
>
> **1 b** :  to play a significant part in bringing about an end or result : many players have contributed to the team's success
>
> He did not contribute to the project.
>
> In order for the team to win, everyone has to contribute.